# Getting Missing Rows inside a table and copy them to another table

Tags: c#, linq

```
var FileProducts = from ProductsRow in ProductRangesDt.AsEnumerable()
                                 join Filee in FileTb.AsEnumerable() on ProductsRow["GEN_CODE"].ToString() equals Filee["GEN_CODE"].ToString()
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     PRODUCT_ID = ProductsRow["PRODUCT_ID"],
                                     PRODUCT_NAME = ProductsRow["PRODUCT_NAME"],
                                     PROVIDER_ID = ProductsRow["PROVIDER_ID"],
                                     PROVIDER_NAME = ProductsRow["PROVIDER_NAME"],
                                     GEN_CODE = ProductsRow["GEN_CODE"],
                                     MIN_QUANTITY = Filee["MIN_QUANTITY"],
                                     MAX_QUANTITY = Filee["MAX_QUANTITY"],
                                     DISCOUNT_VALUE = Filee["DISCOUNT_VALUE"]
                                 };
var s = (from b in FileProducts
                        select  b.PRODUCT_ID).Distinct(); // count=285
var Products = (from ProductsRow in ProductRangesDt.AsEnumerable()
                                select ProductsRow["PRODUCT_ID"]).Distinct(); // count=7159

var result = Products.Except(s); // it's count should be 7159-285
```

I want to get all the `products ID` that are in `Products` and don't exist in `FileProducts` how can i do this ? `result` always return `0` as count

Comment: take a look at this. http://www.datamartist.com/sql-inner-join-left-outer-join-full-outer-join-examples-with-syntax-for-sql-server

Comment: i don't want to use sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) about Except extension method:

> This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate
>   return value is an object that stores all the information that is
>   required to perform the action. The query represented by this method
>   is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its
>   GetEnumerator method directly or by using foreach in Visual C# or For
>   Each in Visual Basic.

So in order to get the real value form your Set differentiation, you need to enumerate your result either by a call to the Count()-Method (`result.Count()`) on using foreach (`foreach (var r in result) { ... }`).

I can't test with your data, but with test data at my disposition, the Except-extension did delivered the correct results.

Comment: yes in deed it turned out that i was missing a small thing in my data . Except did the trick thank you